# how to create a callbackRef with dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

[This blog post](https://medium.com/@teh_builder/ref-objects-inside-useeffect-hooks-eb7c15198780) and [the official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html?source=post_page-----eb7c15198780----------------------#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node) show how to use `useCallback` to create a callback ref.

But neither one has an example of a case where `useCallback` has dependencies.

How should I set that up?

For example, if I do the following, it won't work, because the callback will be triggered without any arguments whenever `myDependency` changes.

```
const [myDependency, setMyDependency] = useState();

const myRef = useCallback(node => {
    doSomeMagic(node, myDependency);
}, [myDependency]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to split the logic out into a `useCallback` and a `useEffect`.  `useCallback` is used to keep track of the node.  `useEffect` is used to trigger whenever the node changes OR `myDependency` changes.

```
const [node, setNode] = useState();
const [myDependency, setMyDependency] = useState();

const myRef = useCallback(node => {
    setNode(node);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    doSomeMagic(node, myDependency);
}, [node, myDependency]);
```